# Cannot perform runtime binding to null reference when assigning value to a ViewBag in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have a controller that cycles through my "Sites" database and gets a value based on their site ID
It looks like this

```
 osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID];                 
 ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID] = osiTotal[s.ID]; // Receive error message on this line
```

And then my View looks like this

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID]</td>
 </tr>
}
```

But I receive the error

**Cannot perform runtime binding to null reference**

I have tried doing this to my view

```
 @foreach (Site s in sites)
{
 <tr>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">Total</td>
                <td style="font-weight : bold;">@ViewBag.OSITotal[1]</td>
 </tr>
}
```

Where I automatically assign the `@ViewBag.OSITotal` a value of "1"
But still receive the same error

So I am the issue has to be when I'm trying to assign the value of osiTotal[s.ID] to the ViewBag

Why is this?

Comment: Does your view code know what `s.ID` is? Show us your view code that declares this variable.

Comment: I added it in @Jasen

Comment: I think the problem is with s.id. try to debug and see s.id contains an int value... maybe it is null

Comment: on which line do you get that error?

Comment: @Sujay I get it on  ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID] = osiTotal[s.ID]; And the "s.ID" is not null

Answer (score 1):

Reasons when this type of exception is invoked:

> The basics of ViewBag is a dynamic type. And you will get the
> exception on at runtime and not at compile time. So you better need to
> check when you MasterPage - Page is loaded you have the values / HTTP
> values into your request which will be the same as you need. [see this link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1715878.aspx?MVC3%20Razor%20Viewbag%20Title%20RuntimeBinderException)
>
> or
>
> Viewbag.Title RuntimeBinderException is caused by the underlying dynamic object that is being
> used. The .NET framework somehow always throws these exceptions. [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203228/runtimebinderexception-when-using-viewbag)

Example:

In Controller:

```
Dictionary<int, string> sites = new Dictionary<int, string> { {0, "zero" }, { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };
var osiTotal = new string[3] { "Manual", "Semi", "Auto" };
string[] temp = new string[osiTotal.Length];
foreach (var s in sites)
    temp[s.Key] = osiTotal[s.Key];
ViewBag.SiteData = temp;
```

View:

```
@{
    Dictionary<int, string> sites = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 0, "zero" }, { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };
}
@foreach (var s in sites)
{
    <p>@ViewBag.SiteData[s.Key]</p>
}
```